# Angular 4 XContent-Type - Nosniff Given

Tags: angular

The problem is the next. I downloaded CKEditor 4 and wanted to import into my project. It works with CDN link  in "index.html" but I want that use without external links. My app will work in only localhost, and don't want to provide it.

The error message what I get back is the next:

Did not load script at '" IP..."/ckeditor_4.5.11/ckeditor.js' because non script MIME types are not allowed when 'X-Content-Type: nosniff' is given

So, when I use the regular cdn script import it works well, but if I want to use without external url it doesn't works as well.

The not package has installed but it doesn't matter.

I imported this into my Index.html:

```
<script src="src/external_modules/ckeditor_4.5.11/ckeditor.js"> </script>
```

Comment: props to the angular team for providing a meaningful error msg. to your question - double check your path - it basically means the path you gave is wrong. remove extra slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's not how you import a file when you want it in local only.

First, you need to define that it is an asset. If not, your file won't be added to the list of vendors, and you will not be able to use it.

To do that, go into your `angular-cli.json`.

Now, either add the file to your `assets` folder, or add its path to the list of assets under the `assets` property.

Next, you will need to add it to your list of scripts. In the same file, under the `scripts` property, add the path to your file.

You will also need to add the style in the `styles` property, if there's one. Like the JS file, you will also need to define it as an asset.

Comment: bundling and minification aside, there should be no technical issue adding css or js tags to the index.html. in fact Angular.Material project suggest you do exactly that if you want to use their icons. https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-6-optional-add-material-icons

Comment: @Stavm I know, but since you're already in the angulra cli config file, might as well put all of your logic in it, and not put it in your index.html file. As a rule of thumb, I put all external resources in the index file, and all of the internal resources in the cli config file. But, for the OP, you **need to declare your file as an asset in both cases**.

Comment: Thanks for help mate !